# Converting an Int to a Bool

Tags: loops, while-loop

I am having issues creating a loop that checks to see if 5 variables are between the variables 10 and 50. I believe I have set up the correct coding, but I am getting an error saying that I cannot convert an int to a bool. Here is what I currently have:

```
        string userName = "";
        int v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = 0;
        float avg;
        float variance;

        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine();

        int i = 1;

        while (i <= 5)
        {
            int InputCheck = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a number {0} between 10 and 50;", i);
            InputCheck = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (InputCheck >= 10 && InputCheck <= 50) 
            {

                if (i >= 10 && i <= 50)
                    i++;
                if (i != 1)
                {
                    InputCheck = v1;
                }
                if (i != 2)
                {
                    InputCheck = v2;
                }

                if (i == 3)
                {
                    InputCheck = v3;
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    InputCheck = v4;
                }
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    InputCheck = v5;
                }
                if (InputCheck < 10 || InputCheck > 50)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is either to high or to low please re-enter a number:");
                }
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your program intended to do? Your while loop only loops 5 times and i variable max value would be 5 so your first if (if (i >= 10 && i <= 50)) is never going to be accessed so your i variable value will always be 1. Maybe i'm missing something...

Comment: I am tasked with having the user enter in 5 numbers between 10 and 50. He wants us to create loops to check and make sure each variable is between these values. He also wants us to only have one console.readline()l;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your **error** comes from this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please input a number {0} between 10 and 50;", i);
```

You are giving an **int** 'i', where it expects a boolean.
Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70x4wcx1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

**As for the rest of your code:**

- Calamar888 is correct, the first if statement you are using for 'i'
  will never evaluate as true.
- Also, the ifs that follow ( if(i !=1),
  etc) will evaluate to true more than once, overwriting values that
  you have already saved ( i != 1 when i = 2, 3, 4, or 5).
- Inside those if statements you are **changing** the value of 'InputCheck', **not saving it**.
- You should consider using arrays to make your program shorter
- Your else "if (InputCheck < 10 || InputCheck > 50)" should not be inside the first if, it will never be true

Assuming that you declare:

```
int v[5]; /* creates array v[0], v[1], ... v[4] */
int i = 0;

while (i<=4){
 /* internal code */
}
```

Something like this should work:

```
/* internal code */

    if (InputCheck >= 10 && InputCheck <= 50) 
        {
           v[i] = InputCheck;   
           i++;

        }
    else if (InputCheck < 10 || InputCheck > 50)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("The number you entered is either to high or to low please re-enter a number:");
        }
```